# How to write a Regex that identifies specific letters plus a minimum amount of numbers

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regex that can locate IDs in a body of text. The ID starts with "DW" and has a minimum of 5 numbers after that. It will only have numbers and no other characters following that.

Correct Examples

- DW40056
- DW4000057

Wrong Examples

- DW4005
- DW405679fg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use word boundaries around `DW` followed by 4 digits then one or more digits:

```
\bDW\d{4}\d+\b
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/tdM6aR2t5cIYE9).

The word boundaries prevent matches with input such as `ABCDW12345XYZ` etc.

Although you could code the digits part as`\d{5,}`, which is simpler than `\d{4}\d+`, not all engines support open-ended quantity ranges. Since you haven’t indicated the language/tool you’re using, this regex is going to work in more situations.

Answer (score 1):

Try this pattern: `DW\d{5,}$`

See [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tDfOCn/3)

Explanation:

- `DW` is two characters that id start with
- `\d` is for 0-9 numbers
- `{5,}` it means `\d` must appear five or more times
- `$` it means the end of string. this cause this pattern just take strings that end with numbers (no more characters after numbers)

Comment: Thank you and I didn't even know that tool existed. I will use that in the future.

Comment: Word boundaries `\b` are also a fine tool. :-)

Comment: @MartinGal yea, I saw another answer used it, I think `$` fine too

Comment: The question states: "I'm trying to write a regex that can locate IDs in a body of text". This means that the use of `$` is not appropiate here. Your answer was better without it.